# What is the patent specifically protecting on this product?

Tags: design-patent, scope, usd675875

In reference to the patent: [US D675,875 S1](https://www.google.com/patents/USD675875)

What exactly is the patent on this product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a design patent! A "design patent" protects the way an article looks, whereas it is the "utility patent" that protects the way an article is used and works. So this patent is `protecting` the way the shot container looks (with the condiment compartment...).

Comment: More specifically, this design patent protects the "[Sidekick Shotglass](http://chilledmagazine.com/cool_products-detail/innovative-barware-introduces-the-sidekick-shot-glass/)" (referenced in the patent) against knock-off products that would seek to imitate the design and dilute the brand.

Comment: There is no way that this patent can be granted, it is too vague, for example if somebody was to change the dimensions of the product then there is no way the patent is applicable

Comment: Please note the patent does not mention dimensions - the rationality of design patents can sometimes be hard to understand.  Please check this link to better understand the Design patent - http://www.ipwatchdog.com/2011/12/20/design-patents-the-under-utilized-and-overlooked-patent/id=21337/